# "Verstehe einer die ..."

Tags: meaning

In den folgenden Beispielen:

> Verstehe einer die Jugend
>
> Verstehe einer die Frauen/Männer
>
> Aber verstehe einer die belgische Kunst.

habe ich drei Fragen:

1) Was bedeutet dieser Ausdruck?

2) Warum wurde der Konjunktiv benutzt?

3) Warum ist *einer* und nicht *man*?

Comment: Das ist nicht der Konjunktiv, sondern der Imperativ.

Comment: Ich denke eher, es ist ein Konjunktiv, und zwar in der Funktion eines Optativs, d.h. einen Wunsch ausdrückend. Das lässt aber nicht definitiv entscheiden, weil die Formen übereinstimmen.

Comment: Das ist m.E. weder ein Konjunktiv, noch ein Imperativ und einen Wunsch drückt es auch nicht aus. Im Gegenteil, es ist ein Appell an die Allgemeinheit die Jugend, die Frauen/Männer oder die belgische Kunst auch nicht zu verstehen und dem Sprecher beizupflichten in seinem Weltschmerz. Die Wortform "Resignativ" gibt es aber wohl nicht - verstehe einer Deutsch und Latein! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Der Sprecher drückt sein Unverständnis aus, und fordert im übertragenen Sinne den Rest der Welt auf, das Besprochene zu verstehen (im Sinne einer Herausforderung).

2) Ich denke, es handelt sich um Imperativ.

3) Man kann "man" nicht herausfordern, einzelne Menschen schon.

Comment: +1, doch man kann sehr wohl den Imperativ auch bei *man* verwenden: ***Man** nehme ein Ei, einen EL Senf, reichlich Majoran und Dill.* — ***Man** verstehe mich bitte nicht falsch!*

Comment: Das ist korrekt, ich bezog mich jedoch auf "herausfordern", nicht auf den (dafür verwendeten) Imperativ.

Comment: *Man nehme...* ist kein regulärer Imperativ, sondern grammatikalisch ein Konjunktiv. Ich sehe gerade, dass es dafür auch die Bezeichnung Adhortativ[1] gibt.

  [1]: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhortativ

Comment: Wenn man das `einer` durch `man` ersetzt, dann entsteht eine syntaktisch korrekte und semantisch gleichbedeutende Variante, die aber einfach unidiomatisch ist. Versuche man doch nicht immer, Idiomatie mit Grammatik zu erklären, in einer Sprache, die über drei Modi und sechs Tempera verfügt, aber fast alles mit Indikativ Präsens und Perfekt löst.

Comment: Ich behaupte, man fordert nur scheinbar auf, das fragliche zu verstehen. Eigentlich fordert man Zustimmung zum Unverständnis. So wie es rhetorische Fragen gibt könnte man versucht sein, von einem rhetorischen Imperativ zu reden - ob die Idee schon mal wer hatte weiß ich nicht.

Answer (score 1):

1) Mittels des Konstrukts *»verstehe einer«* wird eine Art von Klage geführt, dass sich etwas dem Verständnis entzieht. Es schwingt aber immer auch Kritik mit. In den genannten Fällen könnte sie z. B. lauten:

> Mit ihrem Verhalten schaden sich die Jugendlichen doch nur selbst.
>
> Das Handeln der Frau ist irrational.
>
> Die belgischen Künstler sind doch alle geisteskrank.

2) Es geht auch anders:

> Und da soll noch einer die Frauen verstehen!

3) Auch mit *»man«* sind die Aussagen formulierbar:

> Man verstehe die Jugend!
>
> Man verstehe die Frauen/Männer!
>
> Man verstehe die belgische Kunst!

Comment: Man kann es drehen und wenden, wie man will: Teilantwort 3 sieht diskussionswürdig aus.

Comment: @guidot: Man kann es als Klage (mit dem Subtext _»Das ist unmöglich!«_), aber auch als Aufforderung verstehen. Was gemeint ist, muss aus dem Kontext hervorgehen.